# Docksal / Pantheon integration

Tags: 8

I have an inherited Drupal 8 instance that has a nonstandard file configuration. Given then file/folder layout, I am pretty sure it is nearly impossible to run on Pantheon as is.

So - my last Hail Mary before dumping Pantheon and moving to something like Digital Ocean or better yet AWS is to at least get the package up and running via Docksal.

I'm just getting somewhat familiar with Docksal, so three questions;

1) Will it create a platform-agnostic environment on Pantheon that I can at least demo the Drupal 8 build.

2) If yes to #1, is there a step by step set of instructions on how-to-do that?

3) Can Docksal actually provide a way of creating a demo of the Drupal project externally without Pantheon (seems I read somewhere that it could).

Side note:  I've seen plenty of examples on how to pull down a Pantheon created instance into Docksal. Great - but does me no good. My instance was created outside of Pantheon and if Docksal is an alternative, I need to turn it into a Docksal image/container and somehow get that onto Pantheon.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What I had to do was change my project webroot to be 'web'. I have a local docker environment. You also have to provide a pantheon.yml file int he project root that has 'web_docroot: true` in it. After I did that, when I pushed to the repo from Travis CI, the site worked. (You also have to pushed to master, apparently).

Comment: @kevin From what you said, apparently Docksal does not provide an isolated container that would run independently of Pantheon.  I'm making that assumption based on the need to change the project webroot.  Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know how Docksal works, but I am not sure why it would care what the folder is called, so long as you can change the docroot. To be clear, I am using docker4drupal and the Drupal Composer project template. I switched from docroot to web.

Comment: Curious.. what is non standard about it? Can you provide an specific folder example?